# opencv-python object detection

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I'm a beginner in opencv using python. I have many 16 bit gray scale images and need to detect the same object every time in the different images. Tried template matching in opencv python but needed to take different templates for different images which could be not desirable. Can any one suggest me any algorithm in python to do it efficiently.

Comment: please see: [Is there a less restrictive Stack Exchange site specially suited for not too specific questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252777/is-there-a-less-restrictive-stack-exchange-site-specially-suited-for-not-too-spe)

Comment: are you still looking for an answer?

Comment: I would suggest **Gaussian pyramiding**

Comment: try hsv masking

Answer (score 0):

Your question is way too general. Feature matching is a very vast field.
The type of algorithm to be used totally depends on the object you want to detect, its environment etc.

So if your object won't change its size or angle in the image then use Template Matching.

If the image will change its size and orientation you can use SIFT or SURF.

If your object has unique color features that is different from its background, you can use hsv method.

If you have to classify a group of images as you object,for example all the cricket bats should be detected then you can train a number of positive images to tell the computer how the object looks like and negative image to tell how it doesn't, it can be done using haar training.

Answer (score 0):

u can try out sliding window method. if ur object is the same in all samples

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to look for known colors, shapes, and sizes.

You could start by performing an HSV threshold on your image, by converting your image to HSV colorspace and then calling

```
cv2.inRange(source, (minHue, minSat, minVal), (maxHue, maxSat, maxVal))
```

Next, you could use `cv2.findContours` to find all the areas in your image that meet your color requirements. Then, you could use methods such as `boundingRect` and `contourArea` to find specific attributes of the object that you want.

What you will end up with is essentially a 'pipeline' that can take a frame, and look for a shape that fits the criteria you have set. Depending on the complexity of what you want to do (you didn't say what you're looking for), this may or may not work, but I have used it with reasonable success.

GRIP is an application that allows you to threshold things in a visual way, and it will also generate Python code for you if you want. I don't really recommend using the generated code as-is because I've run into some problems that way. Here's the link to GRIP: https://github.com/WPIRoboticsProjects/GRIP

Answer (score 0):

If the object you want to detect has different size in every image and also slightly varies in shape too, then I recommend you use HaarCascade of that object. If the object is very general then you can easily find haar cascade for it online. Otherwise it is not very difficult to make haar cascades(can be a littile time consuming though). 
You can use this tutorial by sentdex to make HaarCascade [here](https://pythonprogramming.net/haar-cascade-object-detection-python-opencv-tutorial/).

Or If you want to know how to use HaarCascades then you can get it on this link
[here](https://pythonprogramming.net/haar-cascade-face-eye-detection-python-opencv-tutorial/).